# Change red reflection in: object mode - material viewport shading - principled shader

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, shaders

When viewing an object in object mode with viewport shading set to material:

Is there a way to change this red reflection to a different color?

I'm using principled shader in blender 2.79

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These reflections are caused by the default Blender viewport OpenGL shading lights, which apparently becomes more visible in materias using the Principled BSDF Shader.

You can change this from the *User Preferences > System* tab under *Solid OpenGL Lights*.

The offending color is by default most likely the last *Specular* entry. Change it to whatever color you like, make sure you *Save User Settings* if you want it set by default.

[image]